# How to access client cookies from NextJS custom document

Tags: next.js

I have a custom NextJS document (TypeScript - _document.tsx) that includes a script element with some js that *needs* to be in `<head>` according to vendor. I'd like to make the inclusion of the script element conditional, depending upon the presence and value of a cookie.

I tried setting this up in `getInitialProps` and examining the context parameter, but only a couple properties exist; notably NOT `req`.

How can I access client cookie values from within a NextJS custom document?

Comment: The `context` parameter does include a `req` property you can use to access the cookies, e.g. `static async getInitialProps(context) { console.log(context.req.cookies); ... }`.